# How to set custom comparator in Java Map of Map?

Tags: java, treemap, sortedmap

```
Map<Character, TreeMap<Integer, String>> topElems = new HashMap<Character, TreeMap<Integer, String>  > ();
```

How to set a custom comparator for the TreeMap in the above statement?

Something like:

```
Map<Character, TreeMap<Integer, String>> topElems = new HashMap<Character, TreeMap<Integer, String> ((x, y) -> y - x)  > ();
```

Comment: _javadoc_ is your friend. Use the [constructor](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html#TreeMap-java.util.Comparator-) that takes a `Comparator` argument.

Comment: for a normal TreeMap, I know how to write it, but the question is how to do it for map of treemap. Could you please provide a code sample?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're attempting to set the `Comparator` in the *type argument*, which is invalid syntax. The type arguments only specify the types, they aren't actual instances. What you would need to do is use the correct `Comparator` for each `TreeMap` you put into the outer `Map`:

```java
Map<Character, TreeMap<Integer, String>> map = new HashMap<>();

TreeMap<Integer, String> treeMap = new TreeMap<>((x, y) -> y - x);
map.put('A', treeMap);
```

Note you cannot *force*, via the compiler, that every `TreeMap` use the same `Comparator` implementation.